# What's the opposite/antonym of "epicene" in the linguistics sense?

Tags: single-word-requests

The title says it all. I am looking for a word used to describe a noun that has different forms for male and female referents, e.g. emperor and empress. I guess "gendered" would work fine, but I wondered if there was a technical term for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there's no special name for them, at least not in English. Latin had, and Spanish has, plenty of such nouns, but they're just thematic inflections (e.g, Lat _filius_ 'son', _filia_ 'daughter'). And gender can include grammatical gender as well as natural human genders. You might want to limit your search to human nouns, for instance.

Comment: "Gender-specific" or "sex-specific" could work.